# Is there a way to truncate string based on the width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table, truncate

I have a table with column of hash's.
I want to truncate the hash to see only few from start and end
I've used this

```
elem.replace(elem.substring(10, elem.length - 10),'...')
```

To see just 10 from start and 10 from end

but on the table it turns out the Z effect

[image]

So I want to truncate based on the width of the text
which I'm getting with the next function

```js
String.prototype.width = function (font) {
  var f = font || '14px Rubik',
    o = $('<div></div>')
      .text(this)
      .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        float: 'left',
        'white-space': 'nowrap',
        visibility: 'hidden',
        font: f
      })
      .appendTo($('body')),
    w = o.width()

  o.remove()

  return w
}
```

I need a function to truncate the strings until the all are same
Something like this but I need help with this function or a better idea.

```js
function smartTruncate(elem) {
  const baseWidth = 160
  let elemWidth = elem.width()

  for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elemWidth > baseWidth) {

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that different characters have different widths. But you can use one of the [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), they have no such problem.

Comment: Or add a fix width in css, which none of these values will exceed. So you don't have to use JavaScript at all to fix this.

Comment: I dont want to use monospace font. I have tried with fixed width and text-overflow but it's not good enough.